# Eclipse - how to reference current feature version inside feature manifest

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, manifest, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

Inside [Enide Node.js feature manifest](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/features/org.nodeclipse.enide.nodejs.feature/feature.xml) I am referencing "org.nodeclipse" feature.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
  id="org.nodeclipse.enide.nodejs.feature"
  label="Enide Node.js"
  version="0.10.0.qualifier"
...

<!-- http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Ffeature_manifest.html -->
<requires>
  <import feature="org.chromium.sdk" version="0.3.9" match="compatible"/>
  <import feature="org.chromium.debug" version="0.3.9" match="compatible"/>
  <import feature="org.nodeclipse" version="0.10.0" match="perfect"/>
  <import feature="com.eclipsesource.jshint.feature" version="0.9.9" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
```

The intention is that "org.nodeclipse" is updated with  "org.nodeclipse.enide.nodejs.feature" and must be of the same version.

Can I reference version like `version=feature.version match="perfect"` ?

Comment: I believe you have to specify an actual version number.